# jQuery - Link draggable elements as "nodes"

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can you "link" up elements so they have lines drawn from one to another ... like graphically?

Something like this: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) for this kind of work.
You can also use [jsPlumb - jQuery plugin](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html)

Comment: Where exactly in this giant library would do this?

Comment: I've just added a jquery plugin for you